# AWS CLI dollar sign '$' escaping when invoking lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

there! I got little problem invoking aws lambda function from cli on Windows, my invocation code looks like this

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name blah-blah-event-generator --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{\"UserName\": \"blah-blah\", \"Pwd\": \"blah$$blah\", \"Operation\": \"blah\"}' response.json
```

And this error occurs

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized character escape '$' (code 36)
```

To overcome this problem I tried to add '' symbol before dollar signs but nothing changes:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name blah-blah-event-generator --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{\"UserName\": \"blah-blah\", \"Pwd\": \"blah\$\$blah\", \"Operation\": \"blah\"}' response.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you need to use double quotation mark (") for the *payload* parameter. The $ is not generating any problem.

Try with this command (I have taken the first command and changed ' by "):

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name blah-blah-event-generator --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload "{\"UserName\": \"blah-blah\", \"Pwd\": \"blah$$blah\", \"Operation\": \"blah\"}" response.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! And I found another solution, just using json external payload-file, here is command: 
```
aws lambda invoke --function-name blah-blah-event-generator --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload file://invoke-payload.json response.json
```